# Filter by date comparison in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I'm trying to filter a set of values in a collection (`messages`) by a date columns. I have two columns:

```
date: Wed September 18, 2013 
mdate: 9/18/2013 6:19:40 PM
```

Using MongoVUE I tried this:

```
{"date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2014-09-12 18:14:58") }}
```

But didn't work and I get this message:

> Syntax or parsing error

What is wrong on the query? What is the proper query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates must be stored as ISODates for MongoDB to see them as dates - your current properties are strings. You will need to convert them to ISODates to query them.

Comment: I have a 4GB DB that's huge, any other solution?

Comment: @ReynierPM no - write a JavaScript to perform the conversion once and start storing dates correctly from your app.

Comment: Can you give me some code to test? I have no idea in how to move all over the records on `messages` collection and convert those two columns into ISODates. I think `d = new Date()` (using column value perhaps I am complete wrong) and then `var nd = d.ISOString(d)` will do the job but I am not sure how to achieve this. I have taken the idea from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)